# how do i change templates on django admin pages?

Tags: python, django, templates, admin

i am walking [through this tutorial for django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/)

in the section: **Customize the admin look and feel** at the bottom it talks about taking files from the default installation of django, (such as: django/contrib/admin/templates) and applying it to your specific site.

it keeps referring to:

```
/home/my_username/mytemplates
```

directory but i don't see that anywhere.  Can someone explain where this mytemplates directory is.  I am supposed to create it?  The tutorial directions are very unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I must defend the honor of the django docs!

```
"/home/my_username/mytemplates", # Change this to your own directory.
```

You are supposed to replace it with your own directory, wherever that might be.

Yes, create a new directory and point to it in your `settings.py`

> **By default, TEMPLATE_DIRS is empty.**
>   So, let's add a line to it, to tell
>   Django where our templates live:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
     "/home/my_username/mytemplates", # Change this to your own directory. )
```

> Now copy the template
>   admin/base_site.html from within the
>   default Django admin template
>   directory in the source code of Django
>   itself
>   (django/contrib/admin/templates) into
>   an admin subdirectory of whichever
>   directory you're using in
>   TEMPLATE_DIRS. **For example**, **if** your
>   TEMPLATE_DIRS includes
>   "/home/my_username/mytemplates", as
>   above, **then** copy
>   django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html
>   to
>   /home/my_username/mytemplates/admin/base_site.html.
>   Don't forget that admin subdirectory.

Comment: thanks . didn't mean to insult the docs.  Should this directory by under the directory of the site directory? or could it be anywhere ?  any suggestions here ??

Comment: @ooo I worship the django docs so I had to pitch in :) Many people put a global templates directory immediately in their project root folder: `myproject/templates`, and use app specific templates as well. `myproject/myapp/templates/myapp/`