# Django template does not change when `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is modified

Tags: django, django-templates

I am following the tutorial in the offical documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/

I am in the section of customizing the templates, but I am running into problems with changing the content of the templates

This is in my settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
print TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

Here is my tree structure

```
└── mysite
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    ├── polls
    └── templates
        └── admin
            └── base_site.html
```

I double check the path using print, which should be correct

```
   ['/Users/mysite/templates']
```

and edit the base_site.html to

```
{% block title %}{{ title }} | {{ site_title|default:_('Poll admin') }}{% endblock %}
```

However it seems like I cannot see the changes when I rerun

```
python manage.py runserver
```

The other questions seems to have a path problem, but I think my path is correct,

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921080/how-do-i-change-templates-on-django-admin-pages
```

Comment: What does it return? Can you add your views and urls?

Comment: @Dorian I had this exact same problem not five hours ago. It occurs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-look-and-feel), in Part 2 of the tutorial. You're just modifying the admin page; no user-defined views or urls have been added yet. The page should have different header text where it says "Django administration". Stopping and restarting the server didn't help. Now I'm having the same problem with the [template examples of the details view from Part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/#use-the-template-system).